# Chart Element - Points: How to create points with loops

Tags: vb.net, winforms, loops

How can I create a `for` loop for this, in VB.Net? (shown below)

the code below adds values to my chart and is populated by labels that are stored on the windows form.

```
With .Points
    .AddXY(0, 0)
    .AddXY(1, LblWkEff1.Text)
    .AddXY(2, LblWkEff2.Text)
    .AddXY(3, LblWkEff3.Text)
    .AddXY(4, LblWkEff4.Text)
    .AddXY(5, LblWkEff5.Text)
    .AddXY(6, LblWkEff6.Text)
    .AddXY(7, LblWkEff7.Text)
    .AddXY(8, LblWkEff8.Text)
    .AddXY(9, LblWkEff9.Text)
    .AddXY(10, LblWkEff10.Text)
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are working with WinForms. Forms have a `Controls` collection which has an overloaded `Item` indexer (default property) accepting either an `Integer` index or the name of a control as `String`.

```
With .Points
    .AddXY(0, 0)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        .AddXY(i, Controls.Item("LblWkEff" & i).Text)
    Next
End With
```

You will produce less faulty code if you have [Option Strict On](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329). If you have, you will need to perform narrowing conversions explicitly.

```
.AddXY(i, CInt(Controls.Item("LblWkEff" & i).Text)) 'Use CInt for the conversion
```

On the other hand an `Integer` is converted automatically to a `String` when used in a string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Like this: (Assuming the controls is added directly to your form)

```
With .Points
    .AddXY(0, 0)
    For i As Integer = 1 to 10
        .AddXY(i, Me.Controls.Item(String.Format("LblWkEff{0}", i)).Text)
    Next
End With
```

I suggest also that you parse the Y axis:

```
.AddXY(i, Integer.Parse(Me.Controls.Item(String.Format("LblWkEff{0}", i)).Text))
```

Comment: @Joseph.Scott.Garza The counter is the variable `i` and the name of the control is `String.Format("LblWkEff{0}", i)`.